# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FROM, when trying to delete table that is joined with itself

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to run a query using hibernate
I do so by following method:

```
private void insertQuery(String toDeleteNewOrOld) {

    String queryString = "";
    if("deleteNew".equals(toDeleteNewOrOld)){
         queryString =
          " delete dmpg2 \n"
        + "from DmPriceGroup dmpg1 \n"
        + " join DmPriceGroup dmpg2 on dmpg1.priceGroupId = dmpg2.priceGroupId \n"
        + " where dmpg1.uid <> dmpg2.uid \n"
        + " and dmpg1.priceGroupName <> dmpg2.priceGroupName \n"
        + " and dmpg1.dmCreateTime > dmpg2.dmCreateTime";
    }
    else if("deleteOld".equals(toDeleteNewOrOld)){
         queryString =
          "DELETE dmpg1\n"
        + "FROM DmPriceGroup dmpg1\n"
        + "join DmPriceGroup dmpg2 on dmpg1.priceGroupId = dmpg2.priceGroupId\n"
        + "where dmpg1.uid <> dmpg2.uid\n"
        + "and dmpg1.priceGroupName = dmpg2.priceGroupName\n"
        + "and dmpg1.dmCreateTime > dmpg2.dmCreateTime\n";
    }

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    writerLogic.executeQuery(getDmEntityClass(), queryString, parameters);
}
```

When I execute it, the deleteold condition querystring is used, but it fails with following error

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FROM near line 2, column 1 [DELETE dmpg1
FROM com.schantz.generallife.dm.model.DmPriceGroup dmpg1
join com.schantz.generallife.dm.model.DmPriceGroup dmpg2 on dmpg1.priceGroupId = dmpg2.priceGroupId
where dmpg1.uid <> dmpg2.uid
and dmpg1.priceGroupName = dmpg2.priceGroupName
and dmpg1.dmCreateTime > dmpg2.dmCreateTime
]
```

Looking at similiar questions, this seems to be caused by faulty syntax, however when I manually run following code on ssms it runs fine

```
DELETE dmpg1
FROM DmPriceGroup dmpg1
join DmPriceGroup dmpg2 on dmpg1.priceGroupId = dmpg2.priceGroupId
where dmpg1.uid <> dmpg2.uid
and dmpg1.priceGroupName = dmpg2.priceGroupName
and dmpg1.dmCreateTime > dmpg2.dmCreateTime
```

Deleting the dmpg1 after DELETE, will make the unexpected token "join" instead. However I don't believe that it would be possible for me to delete from DmPriceGroup without clarifying which joined DmPriceGroup  to delete

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SSMS when I was manually checking the query, but my question is regarding the hibernate jpa query

Comment: remove alias from delete clause and use subquery

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, according to [this](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58003657.shtml) source.

You can instead fetch all the ids, can run a deleteAll() on them (Or maybe write native SQL but I won't prefer that).